# modeless QDialog: closeEvent() not called when application exits?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a modeless dialog that overrides closeEvent() in order to save its state. This works fine if I actually close the dialog. However, if I just exit the application by whatever means (which of course results in my dialog closing), closeEvent() never gets called.

Is this by design? Is it a Qt bug? Is there something like a property I need to set on the widget to tell it to receive close events when the application is shutting down?

I guess I can duplicate the "save state" code in the dialog's destructor, but it would be nicer if I didn't have to.

Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: what programming language is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in Qt that when an application quits via menu command (instead of closing the last `QMainWindow`), the event system is not properly shutdown and objects on the heap are just leaked. It basically just calls `exit();` right away.

I filed a [bug](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-11400) for this on the Mac platform. I don't know what your platform is and if it's also affected.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly along the lines of what I thought the problem might be. If I use a simple Qt example like the one in examples/mainwindows/application, the closeEvent() of the main window gets called if I close the main window, but it isn't called if I insert a QApplication::exit() somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could use a tricky solution: just call `closeEvent` of your dialog from `closeEvent` of MainWindow, passing `QCloseEvent` object as argument. For example:

```
void QtMainWindowTest::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *ev)
{
    _dlg ->closeEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: Indeed, that's a possibility. Thanks. I don't know if that's any less of a maintenance hassle than having another call to saveSettings() in my destructor.

Comment: @Owen: Maybe a maintenance is the same, but calling closeEvent is much cleaner (to me). But it is just a matter of opinion. Regards.